# Is there a way to access the matched URL pattern when attaching to the webRequest event?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

Currently building a webextension and would like to know which URL match pattern was matched in my backgroundscript when the `webRequest.onBeforeRequest` event fired when using the event with a `URLFilter` object.

Unfortunately, the callback only receives a `details` object containing the URL of the matched website, not the match pattern itself. For testing purposes there is also [a way described on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns) to access the module, but is there a way to access the actual matched pattern, or will I need to write my own regexp matching function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, no, Chrome API's Events do not communicate which filter rule matched to the callback.

Since you have the URL, you can perform the matching yourself.

Another solution would be to have a handler per URL pattern. Chrome runtime will route the event to the appropriate callback, and you'll know which one is hit.

Comment: I need to dynamically add either to the `URLFilter` object and regexp the match or dynamically create the listeners. Any idea which one is more efficient?